# DynamoDB unused write Provisioned Capacity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I was checking one of the production dynamodb table in our system, and write provisioned capacity for one of the table was set to 800 units. But seeing the data in the table, seems like data is only written/updated  once per month to that table and the table always have 10 to 15 items in it, with max item size around 10 KB.

My doubt is, if we set the read or write capacity units to very high but never or rarely utilize that much capacity will AWS charge for the provisioned capacity or the actual utilized capacity. Not sure but I think AWS will charge for the provisioned capacity ragardless of what is actually used. Just want to clarify this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They charge for the provisioned capacity - which is why its super-important to keep track of it. Also... higher values can cause re-partitioning of the underlying data.. but at 800 this won't impact you.

Comment: I'm worried about cost, in the snap above it shows estimated cost as 580$ per month. But If I decrease the write capacity units to say 100 , the estimated cost gets decreased by 400$.

Comment: Yeah so that's a pretty high RCU and WCU - just look at the cloudwatch logs and see what your values look like over a long period. You can safely reduce it. And yes, it costs a LOT for higher RCU and WCU.

Answer (score 1):

**They charge for provisioned capacity** because they need to provide the underlying infrastructure to fulfill this.

In your case you should consider [DynamoDB Autoscaling.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AutoScaling.html) Or if your data is updated once per month and you know the date/time you could increase the throughput automatically and scale down after you are finished.